# Java Arrays Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I'm new to java and I recently wrote a program that sorts an array of strings in 
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
 public class
```

Comment: You could simply compare the substring(1, 4) or the two strings. And you could use Arrays.sort(), passing a Comparator, instead of implementing your own sorting algorithm.

Comment: you dont have to take care of comparing with charAt index, `compareTo` method do it internally, means internally two string will be compared at index 1, 2,.. upto String length

Comment: What have you tried? What other searches did you look? Do you want to implement this yourself or use a library?

Comment: @Vishrant I would prefer using CharAt.

Comment: @JB I have no idea what a comparator is

Comment: That's where, Google, the javadoc, etc. are your friends.

Comment: @DonyorM This is my first time doing something like this. I am just trying to use charAt in this situation so I can understand it a little better...

Comment: not sure why you changed the content of your question.

Comment: your sort is called a bubble sort. there are plenty other. wikipedia is very good at describing sort algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

You can still use [Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)) method for this and just provide own customized [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
Arrays.sort(name,
    (String left, String right) ->
        left.substring(1).compareTo(right.substring(1))
);
```

If you want to implement this on your own, note that comparator is supposed to return 0 if the paramaters are equal, negative number if the left is lower and positive number if the right is lower. So the comparator character by characters will look like:

```
Arrays.sort(name,
    (String left, String right) -> {
        // starting from index 1 and going until reaching end of strings
        for (int i = 1; i < left.length() && i < right.length(); ++i) {
            int diff = left.charAt(i)-right.charAt(i);
            if (diff != 0)
                return diff;
        }
        // if strings are equal so far, return that the lower is the shorter one
        return left.length()-right.length();
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks but that looks pretty complicated..I'm trying to understand how to use  things like CharAt to solve this..

Comment: @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000 Please mention java version 1.8 or later for using lambda expression

Comment: @KidKool , You could also follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35402555/how-do-i-sort-an-array-of-strings-by-the-second-char-of-each-string/35402811#35402811

Comment: @Zbynek What does -> mean? What is .length? Isn't there a more basic way of doing this using charAt?

Comment: @mmuzahid What are Collections? What does .trim mean?

Comment: @KidKool, The Java ``collections`` framework gives the programmer access to prepackaged data structures as well as to algorithms for manipulating them. ref-http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm

AND where you need ``trim()``?

Comment: @Zbynek  Is it necessary to use arrays.sort in order to make a program like this?

Comment: @mmuzahid Do i have to use arrays.sort in order to use charAt to solve this? is there an even more basic way?  btw Someone on the link you passed me used trim()..

Comment: @KidKool : It definitely isn't. You can write your own sort implementation but frankly why to reinvent the wheel. So I suggested existing implementation which is part of core java. However, moving the comparator body to separate method isn't big deal I believe.

Comment: @Zbynek So how would I do it without using arrays.sort?  I am dumbfounded as to how I could implement charAt without using arrys.sort..

Comment: @KidKool If you are using java version **1.8** or later which support **lambda expression** then you should take this answer given by **Zbynek Vyskovsky**. If you version is older than 1.8 you could choose the accepted answer from my previously shared link.

Comment: I edited my code but is there a way to do this using charAt but NOT using arrays.sory or lambadas?

Comment: @KidKool : `charAt` has nothing to do with `Arrays.sort` or lambdas. Here we use `charAt` only to implement the `Comparator.compareTo` method. Whether you then pass the comparator to `Arrays.sort` or call it from your own sorting implementation, doesn't really matter. So to avoid `Arrays.sort` take the code in the answer and put it into your own method `int myCompare(String left, String right) { the code... }` and call it from the sorting part.

Comment: @Zbynek So I take the code from my current answer(the edited version) and put it In a new method/function? and then I call it before/after I sort?

Answer (score 0):

*Since you have already implemented the user input and displaying the values, I won't take that into consideration.*

There are two things that need to be implemented:

1. Comparing two objects with eachother;
2. Based on the result of the comparison, insert one of the items either before or after the element.

These are two separate functions.

### Comparing two objects with eachother

Take a look at the [`Comparator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface. It lets you implement the way how objects are compared. The one and only method of the `Comparator` interface is the method `compare(String o1, String o2)`. You only need to make sure that:

- if both objects should have the same order, return `0`. In our example below, **Saab** and **Jaguar** are the same, because we're trying to order only by the second character, which is an **a** for both.
- if `o1` is 'less' than `o2`, return `-1`. In our example, comparing **Saab** with **Opel** would return `-1`, because the **a** is 'less' than the **p**.
- if `o1` is 'greater' than `o2`, return `1`. In our example, comparing **Skoda** with **Jaguar** would return `1`, because the second character of **Skoda** (the **k**) is 'greater' than the second character of **Jaguar** (the **a**).

By the way, in your original code, you used the method `String.compareTo()`, which is almost *exactly the same* as the `Comparator<String>.compare(String, String)` method.

```
class MyCustomComparator implements Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String t, String t1) {
        // We assume that the strings are not null
        // We also assume that the length of the
        // strings is at least 2.
        if (t.charAt(1) < t1.charAt(1)) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (t.charAt(1) > t1.charAt(1)) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

### Inserting the elements at the right spots

Once you have defined your own Comparator, the only thing you have to do is pass it to the method `Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`, which accepts as first argument your array with the strings, and as second argument your own defined Comparator.

Example:

```
String[] array = new String[] {
    "Saab",
    "Opel",
    "Skoda",
    "Jaguar",
    "Chevrolet"
};
// Result when ordering by second char:
// Saab, Jaguar, Chevy, Skoda, Opel

// Sort the array
Arrays.sort(array, new MyCustomComparator());
```

And if you *really*, *really*, *really* want to avoid the `Arrays.sort()` method, you can just reinvent the wheel:

```
/** Returns a new string array with the elements sorted */
String[] sort(String[] strings, Comparator<String> c) {
    List<String> sortedArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String str : strings) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < sortedArray.size(); i++) {
            if (c.compare(str, sortedArray.get(i)) < 0) {
                sortedArray.add(i, str);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == sortedArray.size()) {
            sortedArray.add(strings[i]);
        }
    }
    return sortedArray.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use your original code with these modifications:

```
void myCustomCompareTo(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.charAt(1) < s2.charAt(1)) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (s1.charAt(1) > s2.charAt(2)) {
        return 1;
    }
    else { // They're equal
        return 0;
    }
}

String[] sortMe(String[] strs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5 - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (strs[j].myCustomCompareTo(name[j + 1]) > 0) {
                // Swap the two values
                String temp = name[j];
                strs[j] = strs[j + 1];
                strs[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return strs;
}
```

### Other notes

- I see you have a hard time understanding the code of the given answers. I suggest you start examining the `String` class. You will read about the `length()` and the `charAt(int)` method. Especially `length()` is used often; I suggest you take that into account. Also, learning [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) might also help.
- Almost every programmer I know is using the variable `i` in a `for` loop, instead of `x`. You should consider doing so too.
- You are not using the variable `num`.
- The arrows (`->`) [Zbynek Vyskovsky - kvr000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4787126/zbynek-vyskovsky-kvr000) is using, are part of [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Lambda expressions are [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), they make things easier to express (but not necessarily to read, especially for newcomers in the Java field).

  For instance,

  ```
  Arrays.sort(name,
      (String left, String right) ->
          left.substring(1).compareTo(right.substring(1))
  );
  ```

  is exactly the same as this:

  ```
  Arrays.sort(name, new Comparator() {

      @Override
      public int compare(String left, String right) {
          return left.substring(1).compareTo(right.substring(1));
      }
  );
  ```

  But in fact, this is beyond the scope of this.

Comment: I don't get it..That program doesn't  get user inputed strings. Does that program even display the sorted list of strings after they are sorted? I am so confused..

Comment: Do I have to use arrays.sort or is there a more basic way? Im just trying to learn everything I can...Thanks for your help..The edited post was great.

Comment: I edited my code but is there a way to do this using charAt but WITHOUT using arrays.sory or lambdas?

Comment: @KidKool That is possible. I'm going to update my answer. But ... why should you not use `Arrays.sort()`?

Comment: I just want to see if I can do this without using that library..It seems a little to advanced for me...I wanna break this down in a really basic way...

Comment: I forgot to mention this before but is there a way to do it without using Comparator, arrays.sort, and lambdas?

Comment: @KidKool I have updated the answer. There is a way of not using a `Comparator`: you simply have to write your own method which compares two items.

Comment: I saw that..Thanks...Do I have to use Comparator?

Comment: @KidKool It is by far the best way to make one method to **compare two elements**, and another to **insert the item at the right position**. In your original code you just used almost the same thing: you used `str1.compareTo(str2)` while I am using `Comparator.compare(str1, str2)`. They do **exactly the same thing**. I do not know why you allow yourself to use the `String.compareTo()` method, but disallow yourself to use `Comparator.compare(String, String)`.